# ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword when inserting data

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ora-00928

I am trying to insert data into database but I am getting this exception:

> java.sql.SqlException:[Oracle][ODBC]ORA-00928:missing SELECT keyword

Comment: You might have a bug in your query, but as you've not provided it, it's kinda hard to say where it is.....

Comment: What's your SQL statement generating this error? Edit your question to include your exact code.

Comment: If you don't provide your SQL this is going to be closed and deleted soon...

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're trying to insert data into an Oracle table. Try formulating a statement like this:

```
 INSERT INTO MyTable(Column1, Column2)
 VALUES (1, 'SomeString');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Column1, Column2)
     SELECT Foo, Bar
     From MySecondTable;
```